# Position of the legend

Tags: r, position, legend

i would like to write a function with graphical output of original data regression and one for modified data. The original data regression should be an option. Moreover there should be legends in the graphs. And here is my problem:
If i choose the option: orig.plot=FALSE, everything works ok.
But when i choose the other option: orig.plot=TRUE, the position of my legends is not very satisfying.

```
# Generation of the data set

set.seed(444)

nr.outlier<- 10

x<-seq(0,60,length=150);
y<-rnorm(150,0,10);
yy<-x+y;
d<-cbind(x,yy)


# Manipulation of data:
ss1<-sample(1:nr.outlier,1) # sample size 1
sri1<-sample(c(1:round(0.2*length(x))),ss1) # sample row index 1
sb1<-c(yy[quantile(yy,0.95)<yy])# sample base 1
d[sri1,2]<-sample(sb1,ss1,replace=T) # manipulation of part 1

ss2<-nr.outlier-ss1 # sample size 2 
sri2<-sample(c(round(0.8*length(x)+1):length(x)),ss2) # sample row index 2
sb2<-c(yy[quantile(yy,0.05)>yy])# sample base 2
d[sri2,2]<-sample(sb2,ss2,replace=T) # manipulation of par 2



tlm2<-function(x,y,alpha=0.95,orig.plot=FALSE,orig.ret=FALSE){

m1<-lm(y~x)
res<-abs(m1$res)
topres<-sort(res,decreasing=TRUE)[1:round((1-alpha)*length(x))] # top alpha*n residuals
topind<-rownames(as.data.frame(topres)) # indices of the top residuals
x2<-x[-as.numeric(topind)] #
y2<-y[-as.numeric(topind)] # removal of the identified observations

m2<-lm(y2~x2)
r2_m1<-summary(m1)$'r.squared'
r2_m2<-summary(m2)$'r.squared'
if(orig.plot==TRUE){
    par(mfrow=c(2,1))
    plot(x,y,xlim=range(x),ylim=c(min(d[,2])-30,max(d[,2]+30)),main="Model based on original data")
    abline(m1$coef);legend("topleft",legend=bquote(italic(R)^2==.(r2_m1)),bty="n")
}
plot(x2,y2,xlim=range(x),ylim=c(min(d[,2])-30,max(d[,2]+30)),main="Model based on trimmed data")
abline(m2$coef);

legend("topleft",legend=bquote(atop(italic(R)^2==.(r2_m2),alpha==.(alpha))),bty="n")

return(if(orig.ret==TRUE){list(m1=m1,m2=m2)} else{m2})
}

tlm2(d[,1],d[,2])

tlm2(d[,1],d[,2],orig.plot=T)
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: You are currently expecting us to guess at how you will be calling the function `tlm2`. Why not instead complete the example by editing your questioon?

Comment: In the "orig.plot=T" alternative the legend lies somewhere in the middle of the left side. But it should lie "topleft"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `atop` is essentially a division (i.e. x/y) without plotting the division bar. It also centers the denominator. The solution is to use `expression` instead of `bquote`. However, to mix expressions and variables, you need to use `substitute` and `eval`:

Here's what your legend call should look like:

```
legend("topleft",legend=c(eval(substitute(expression(italic(R)^2==my.r2), list(my.r2 = r2_m2))) ,
                          eval(substitute(expression(alpha==my.alpha), list(my.alpha = alpha)))
                          )
                          ,bty="n")
```

And here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Hello P Lapointe,
when i use:
    par(mfrow=c(2,1))
it doesn't work so well, so i don't know hot to insert it into my function. Did You print Your results separately?

Comment: I did not print separately. I only changed the second `legend` in your function.

Comment: I have done the same and am using RStudio, but my result doesn't look so nice as Yours. The second legend is split into two and badly placed within points (I don't know hot to insert a plot hier). May it be because of my version?

Comment: Usually, in RStudio you an click on zoom in the plots tab to get you chart in a bigger format which can be resized manually. However, legends do not play well with resizing. So the solution is to write `windows(width=8, height=8)` at the begining of your R program. This will open a window (usually behind Rstudio). Units are in inches.